# how do we manage functions calling in for loop of python program?

Tags: python, list, function, csv, for-loop

I have two files, `1.csv` and `ss.csv`.  `1.csv` is a series of transaction records, while `ss.csv` is a list of keywords.  I want to sort the transactions records from `1.csv` based on the keywords in `ss.csv`.  Then I want to write the sorted data into files named `<keyword>.csv` where each record is in the file with the appropriate name.

This is the beginning of my script.

```
import csv

#all the variables and list
#new_values = []
old_values = []
second_var_ls = ''
second_var_str = ''
second_csv = ''
```

Here I am reading the two files `1.csv` and `ss.csv`

```
#reading main file
first_file = open('1.csv')
first_var = csv.reader(first_file)

#reading second file containing keywords
second_file = open('ss.csv')
second_var = csv.reader(second_file)
```

My main problem is in the function below.  This function is supposed to match the contents of the two files and store them in `new_values`, while `old_values` contains those items that are left and will be used to create a new file with the match keyword.  I want this function to handle a few different things.  It should:

- Read the list
- Match items from `1.csv` with `ss.csv`
- Store the matched items in `new_values`
- Then write the members of `new_values` to a new file with the keyword name

```py
#function to match with the contents of the 1.csv
def match_content(first_var,second_var_str,second_csv):
    new_values=[]
    for row in first_var:
        if second_var_str in row[2]:
            for i in row[2]:
                new_values.append(row)
                print new_values
                break
        new_file = open(second_csv,'w')
        new_var = csv.writer(new_file, dialect ='excel')
        new_var.writerows(new_values)   
    return
```

This funciton takes `ss.csv` as a list, converts it into a string and calls `match_content`.

```
#function to convert ss.csv list into strings
def lis_to_str(second_var):
    for i in second_var:
        second_var_ls = i
        second_var_str = ''.join(map(str,second_var_ls))
        #print second_var_str
        second_csv = second_var_str+'.csv'
        #print second_csv
        match_content(first_var,second_var_str,second_csv,)
```

This last function creates the remaining list by taking values from `old_values`.

```
#function to create the remaining list
def remai_lis(old_values):
    remain_fil = open('remaining.csv','wb')
    remain_wb = csv.writer(remain_fil, dialect='excel')
    remain_wb.writerows(old_values)
    return
```

Then I call the first function the automate the entire process.

```
lis_to_str(second_var)
```

Sample input: 
`1.csv` contains entries like

```
Waybill Contents    Amount  COD Amount  Type
929780  13121248171 lkjljsad;k baggit kjlaLSKL; 5356    2992    COD
929780  13121248171 sakssk adidas kjljl;j   5356    2992    COD
929789  13118218221 lkjljsad;k baggit kjlaLSKL; 1935.15 0   Pre-paid
929789  13118218221 sakssk adidas kjljl;j   1935.15 0   Pre-paid
930025  13118221253 lkjljsad;k baggit kjlaLSKL; 5024.53 0   Pre-paid
930025  13118221253 sakssk adidas kjljl;j   5024.53 0   Pre-paid
931132  13121303740 lkjljsad;k baggit kjlaLSKL; 2997    1947    COD
931132  13121303740 sakssk adidas kjljl;j   2997    1947    COD
931138  13121302944 dhjhk reebok jhkjl;lkk  955 614 COD
931326  11157735855 dhjhk reebok jhkjl;lkk  167 197 COD
931441  11157740534 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  3746    2025    COD
931816  59626604556 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  1999    1999    COD
931199  13118445850 dhjhk reebok jhkjl;lkk          
931621  59626596090 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  595 595 COD
```

And `ss.csv` contains input like

```
yepme
reebok
adidas
baggit
```

The only output I get is in `yepme.csv` which has the matched contents of the word `"yepme"`

```
931441  11157740534 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  3746    2025    COD

931816  59626604556 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  1999    1999    COD

931621  59626596090 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  595 595 COD

931421  11157961034 abc yepme sdgdjdjh  177 207 COD
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The code isn't working right I need to make it work in simple language I have two csv files one has a large content in many columns and one has a single column with certain entries,I want to match the certain entries in the main file and copy them in a new file which will be named as those certain entires if I have word xyz it matches all the xyz and copy them in the list and then make a file xyz.csv and its content in it.Hope I am able to communicate it with you

Comment: Now that you've described what you want your code to do, you need to explain how it does not match what you want. What is the code supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: It is creating only the first file with its content xyz.csv and xyz matched contents but not for rest of the keywords.may be some problem in the for loop of match_content function

Comment: hope now you can help me with an answer @Gabe

Comment: can you give us some sample input and output please?

Comment: @Dannnno I have updated my answer with input and output csv sheets

Comment: Aren't those supposed to be comma separated?

Comment: what needs to be comma separated?

Comment: I have been doing like this it works to a certain extent but not getting results for reebok adidas and remaining

Comment: well csv stands for comma-separated values, meaning they should look like `Waybill,Contents,Amount,COD,Amount,Type` instead of being separated by spaces

Comment: Can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making two assumptions here.  The first is that you're using Python 2.7, and the second is that you have actual csv files.  If either of those is not true then this won't work.

The first step is to extract the different categories.

```
>>> with open("ss.csv") as f:
...     categories = f.read().split()
>>> categories
["yepme", "reebok", "adidas", "baggit"]
```

Then we want to make files for each of those.

```
>>> files = {category: open("{}.csv".format(category), "w") 
...          for category in categories}
```

This gives us a dictionary like `{"yepme": <file-object>, etc}`.  Then we read your main csv file in.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("1.csv", "r") as csv_file:
...    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
...    header = csv_reader.next()
...    for file_ in files.itervalues():
...        file_.write(','.join(header))
...    while True:   # csv_reader.next() will raise a StopIteration when empty
...        try:
...            line = csv_reader.next()
...        except StopIteration: break
...        category = line[3]
...        if category in files:
...            files[category].write(','.join(line))
```

Then we want to close our files

```
>>> for file_ in files.itervalues():
...    file_.close()
```

Comment: Then check your indentation.  I wrote this for use in IDLE, not in a script.  You'll have to make some adjustments there.

Comment: sorry to bother you but I am a noob in python.Now getting stop iteration error why?because my fields are empty or what?I have both the csv files

Comment: You need to add my change

Comment: list object has no attribute itervalues -getting this  (sorry for pissing you off again and again)

Comment: Sorry. Replace categories in the line `for file_ in categories.itervalues()`  with `files`

Comment: Also, based on the file you copy pasted into the comments earlier its unclear about the indentation of that last segment.  That should be outside of the while loop

Comment: Now running without any errors but not pasting the contents only the header waybill no order and all no data

Comment: Add a print statement after the line `category = line[3]` and make sure it gives you the correct keyword

Comment: the print statement giving me correct output but still getting blank csv files

Comment: I can't tell why it isn't working from here.  Do some debugging on your own and if you can get more information post it here.